# TSQL: error while converting timestap to integer

Tags: sql, integer, timestamp

I have:

```
cast(convert(varchar(255), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121) as int) as MYDATENUMBER
```

Being 121: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm (24h)

This is the error that I get:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016-11-16 10:28:47.330' to data type int.

MYDATENUMBER is defined as INT

Any idea on why I am getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to a `VARCHAR(255)` and then casting  a `VARCHAR` to an `INT`

try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121)  MYDATENUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS INT) AS MYDATENUMBER
```